# Depractions while upgrading ember-js to 1.12.0 and ember-cli to 0 0.2.5

Tags: javascript, ember.js, upgrade, ember-cli

I am upgrading my 
Emberjs => from 1.10.0 to 1.12.0
Ember-cli =>  from 0.1.12 to 0.2.5

While i am figuring out most of the deprecations there are few which i am not able to understand. PFB the same

1. DEPRECATION: Ember.required is deprecated as its behavior is inconsistent and unreliable. Where is this used and how to change it?
2. DEPRECATION: `lookupFactory` was called on a Registry. The
   `initializer` API no longer receives a container, and you should use
   an `instanceInitializer` to look up objects from the container. 

   I do understand this issue but my initializer does not use lookup at all. PFB the code of my initializer.

//app/initializer/abc

```
initialize: function(registry, app) {
  app.register('store:main', Store);
  // Inject into each route a store property with an instance of store:main
  app.inject('route', 'store', 'store:main');
  // Inject into each controller a store property with an instance of store:main
  app.inject('controller', 'store', 'store:main');
}
```

//app/initializer/def

```
initialize: function(registry, app) {
        // Register the session object.
        app.register('session:main', Session);

        // Inject the session object into all controllers.
        app.inject('controller', 'session', 'session:main');
    }
```

3. DEPRECATION: Using the context switching form of {{each}} is
   deprecated. Please use the block param form (`{{#each bar as
   |foo|}}`) instead. See
   http://emberjs.com/guides/deprecations/#toc_more-consistent-handlebars-scope
   for more details.

    I understand here that `{{#each foo in bar itemController="abc"}}` should be changed to `{{#each bar itemController="abc" as |foo|}}`. But my code is as below and does not have `"in"`, meaning using this context!

   `{{#each paged itemController="class.adm.man.stop-term"}}`
   How can i change this?

Comment: These deprecation notes doesn't always mean that it's your fault - troubles can be in any of ember addon which you use. For example, I got the note like your second one because of using of ember-simple-auth (see this [issue](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/issues/517) )

Answer (score 2):

Following your list:

1. Seems like it's an ember-data related [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2910). If not, I'm sure there is another addon which use it, but not you. Thus nothing you can do.
2. The same thing. I've already introduced an example as a comment. You code looks good for me, so, I believe, nothing you can do there as well.
3. Ember tries to make more consistent and explicit scopes. `in` part is not deprecated for now, so the simplest solution is to add dummy `in` part, for example `{{#each page in paged itemController="class.adm.man.stop-term"}}`. But in general I'd recommend to use more complex solution - to create an `ItemList` component and refactor it as:

---

```
{{#each paged as |page|}}
  {{item-list model=page}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: thanks for your points. Few notes though!
For first and last i got the answer in ember discussion, for others who want to know - http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/depractions-while-upgrading-ember-js-to-1-12-0-and-ember-cli-to-0-0-2-5/8056 . Your second point is good, i forgot to consider addons and other libraries, so upvoting for that : ). Your third point is wrong, "in" is already deprecated, we need to use "as". For an answer kindly refer to the link i provided : )